# Python Pandas - Error with if_exists='Append' for SQL Server: Error converting data type nvarchar to float

Tags: python, sql-server, excel, pandas

Getting the error `(pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Error converting data type nvarchar to float. (8114)` when attempting to append a excel document to a currently existing table in SQL Server.

The way the program works is there is a first instance that adds the imports the excel document to SQL server using `if_exists='replace'` and then every subsequent instance of imports during the run session are appended with `if_exists='append'`. The error I am receiving would lead me to believe that I have defined one of the columns with the incorrect data type but I have tried both using the SSMS Import Wizard mappings and going through each line and dropping/creating the table.

Has anyone run into an issue like this before? It works fine when using `if_exists='replace'` but not for `if_exists='append'.`

Here is an example of the code I am running (paths and passwords omitted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import sys
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pyodbc
import os
import datetime

class Data_Initialize:
    def __init__(self, instance):
        SERVER = 'localhost\xxx'
        DATABASE = 'xxx'
        DRIVER = 'SQL SERVER'
        USERNAME = xxx
        PASSWORD = xxx
        DATABASE_CONNECTION = 'mssql+pyodbc://localhost\xxx/xxx?driver=SQL SERVER'
        
        engine = create_engine(DATABASE_CONNECTION)
        
        df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Matt\Downloads\MLS ROI Calc.csv')
        df = df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\Matt\Documents\xxx\MLS ROI Calc.xlsx',  index=False)

        df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Matt\Documents\xxx\MLS ROI Calc.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1',  engine='openpyxl')
        try:
            if instance == 1:
                df.to_sql(con=engine.connect(), name='Splitt_Housing_Data_Crawler2', index=False, if_exists='replace')
                print("Data successfully transferred for initial instance...")

            else:
                df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
                df.to_sql(con=engine.connect(), name='Splitt_Housing_Data_Crawler2', index=False, if_exists='append')
                print("Data successfully transferred for subsequent [" + str(instance) + "] instance...")
        except Exception as e:
            print("ERROR - Data transfer FAILED. - " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
            print(e)

        os.remove(r'C:\Users\Matt\Downloads\MLS ROI Calc.csv')
        time.sleep(.75)

        os.remove(r'C:\Users\Matt\Documents\xxx\MLS ROI Calc.xlsx')
```

[image]

Comment: My guess is a `NaN` (float type) trying to migrate to a varchar column. Reduce number of columns to isolate issue: `df[list of some columns].sql(...)`. Also, why convert to Excel workbook to later delete it?

Comment: It seems an odd thing to convert a CSV file to Excel format before trying to read its data in to SQL. What was the problem you were trying to solve by doing that? Why not read the CSV file directly into SQL?